# linking two objects // updating value on first and second

Tags: javascript, oop

```
function associate( obj1 ,obj2 , key ){
    if(typeof key === 'object'){
        for ( var i in key )
            associate(obj1, obj2 , key[i]);
    } else {
        obj1.watch(key, function (id, oldval, newval) {
                obj2[id] = newval;
                return newval;
        });
    }

}
```

I wrote this function because if have to different obj and both need to be updated.
What do you think about this function?

```
  obj = { key1: 'value2', key2: 'value2'} 
  obj2 =  {key1: 'value2', key2 : 'value2'}

  associate( obj ,obj2 , 'key1' )

  obj.key1 = 'new value';

  console.log(obj.key1) 
  --> 'new value'

  console.log(obj2.key1) 
  --> 'new value'
```

Comment: Smells a bit of CW (Community Wiki).

Comment: I think it is a function. I could be wrong. It might take parameters. Not sure about that either.

Comment: What is the question here? What do we think? Thats way too broad.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. At all.

```
return obj1[id] = obj2[id] = newval;
```

That in particular isn't going to get you anywhere.

Feel free to use http://www.jslint.com/ should you want to find issues in your code.

Comment: its working, thats not the problem, the question is, is this good practice?

Comment: Byt the fact that it, in theory(which we all know isn't the same as practice) shouldn't work - I'm going to say no, it isn't.

Comment: okay, i changed to  'obj2[id] = newval; return newval;' should it now work even in theory?

Comment: There are no errors now. So, yes, it works, albeit confusing. But that's just because it's out of context